# Документирование Delphi

Tags: delphi, документация

Не подскажите "удобную" систему для документирования исходников Delphi что то вроде doxegena для с

Comment: К сожалению вопросы опросники здесь не приветствуются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation Insight, встроен в Delphi начиная с версии XE (если мне не изменяет память). Вызывается Ctrl+Alt+D, или ищите его в меню.